# Custom segue push like with back button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, back-button, segue

I’m trying to build my custom segue, similar in behavior to standard Push segue, but in my case I want to use custom buttons to switch between screens (no tab bars will fit to this app, any modal segue is no good either). The main screen is a custom graphics and the screen to segue to is a map. User to choose the point on the map, hit done and come back to the main screen with it’s coordinates. 
I’m trying to connect ViewControllers with custom segue.

I research a lot of solution across the Internet and found one, which can fit, but the code is scatter all around ViewControllers and AppDelegate (I’m not certain if Apple will accept it). I’m trying put whole code to a CustomSegue.m /h. The success is partial because using technique (below) it segues to the second ViewControler but I can’t figure out how to dismiss the second and come back to main screen. I tried various techniques but when I run it the compiler terminates app with bunch of errors. Neither errors nor warnings before building and running. I also tried to dismiss it with a button using [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; or [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; they work when I try modal segues but with my code with bad result.

Does anyone have a suggestion on a neat way of doing this. I’m stack on this problem for the last couple of days. I see that kind of segues transitions in a lot apps so it seems to be quite popular, easy solution. I’m not much experienced in Xcode only couple of mo. 
This is my custom segue (with QuartzCore animation).

```
#import "CustomTabBarSegue.h"

@implementation CustomTabBarSegue


 -(void)perform {
    UIViewController *src = (UIViewController*)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController*)[self destinationViewController];

    UIView *currentView = src.view;
    UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];
    UIView *newView = dst.view;
    [theWindow addSubview:newView];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];

    transition.delegate = self;
    transition.duration = 1;

    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn; 
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight;


    [[theWindow layer] addAnimation:transition forKey:@"MySegue"];
 }

@end
```

Below is code for my button back from destinationVC. (doesn't work)

```
- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender
```

{

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^() {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue" sender:self];
}];
```

}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I MAY understand what you are trying to do. Correct me if I'm wrong though. You want to go to one view then hit a back button to come back. Correct? To do this with story boards is easy. Put a NavigationController as your initial view and set the root view controller for the navigation controller to the main menu. From there you want to do a PUSH segue and to go back you want to do a POP.

Calling the push segue is the normal way to call a segue, but the pop is a little different. The code to pop back one view is: `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`. The code to pop back to the root view controller is: `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.

I believe this is what you wanted to do. No need for custom segues.

Comment: Sorry in advance, English my second language, on a top of this I'm beginner-ish stage of my IOS adventure. My question to your answer is: Is the Push your talking about possible to build without top bar. The top bar would destroy the whole effect. Is it possible you can post some code or a link to a ready example? I would be more than grateful. Thank you.

Comment: If you click on the navigation controller you add in the story board and go to it's settings, you can uncheck showing the top bar.

Comment: Works really great. Thank You so much. Looks like sometimes the most difficult are most simple solutions.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as correct, and rate it up! Thanks!